# Least privileged GH Personal Access Token for registering self-hosted GitHub Actions runner

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to make the process of creating/installing/configuring/registering a self-hosted GH Actions runner on an EC2 instance

I have found the script below to work when passed to the instance's `user-data`

```bash
su - ubuntu -c 'mkdir -p actions-runner && cd actions-runner'
su - ubuntu -c 'curl -o actions-runner-linux-x64-2.303.0.tar.gz -L https://github.com/actions/runner/releases/download/v2.303.0/actions-runner-linux-x64-2.303.0.tar.gz'
su - ubuntu -c 'tar xzf ./actions-runner-linux-x64-2.303.0.tar.gz'
su - ubuntu -c './config.sh --unattended --url '${github_repo_url}' --pat '${github_pat}' --name '${name}'  --labels '${labels}' --replace'
su - ubuntu -c 'sudo ./svc.sh install ubuntu'
su - ubuntu -c 'sudo ./svc.sh start'
```

Currently I am using a rather broad-scoped PAT. What are the minimum scopes such a PAT should have?

What if I want to create org-wide runner?

Comment: I would suggest to create GitHub App and give least permissions to it instead of using user-specific PAT's for runner registration/deletion. Following links may help you with Least privileged permissions. [About Self Hosted Runners](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/self-hosted-runners?apiVersion=2022-11-28#about-self-hosted-runners-in-github-actions) & [Organization Self Hosted Runners](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/permissions-required-for-github-apps?apiVersion=2022-11-28#organization-self-hosted-runners)